# Hyperbolic functions identity problem

Tags: complex-numbers

We know the identity $\tanh(ix)=i  \tanh(x)$.

> My question: is it true that $\tanh^{-1}(ix) = i  \tanh^{-1}(x)$ ?

If not then is there a similar identity for arctangents?  I think there might not be but would like to know how to find one.

Comment: Note that the "known" identity is wrong. We have $\tanh (ix) = i \tan x$, not $i\tanh x$.

Comment: please check it

Comment: $$\tanh (ix) = \frac{\sinh (ix)}{\cosh (ix)} = \frac{\frac12(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})}{\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})} = \frac{i\sin x}{\cos x} = i \tan x$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start. Assume $y=\tanh^{-1}(ix)$ and then apply $\tanh$ to both sides 
and do some manipulations and see what you get.

**Note:** As in the comment

> $$ \tanh(ix)=i\tan(x). $$

Comment: Also note that 1/i = -i, and that will get you a similar but not quite the same relationship that you are looking for.

Comment: Well, to follow this line of reasoning, you actually need that tan(ix) = i tanh(x) , rather than the above, but you could get that by setting z = ix and knowing that tangent is an odd function.